# Why does the VS compiler complain about not finding the assembly when using nested config files, but the ASP.NET engine in IIS has no issues?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, data-visualization

I'm looking at a web.config right now in ASP.NET WebForms .NET 3.5 that's got all the primary config files broken out like thus:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <membership configSource="config\membership.config"/>
    <authentication configSource="config\authentication.config"/>
    <machineKey configSource="config\machineKey.config"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true"/>
    <pages configSource="config\pages.config"/>
    <httpHandlers configSource="config\httpHandlers.config"/>
    <httpModules configSource="config\httpModules.config"/>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

and if I compile the source in VS 2010 it complains about not being able to find the .NET DataVisualization library (`Error 14  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    sourcecodefile  line`) and if I compile it with the aspnet_compiler or just drop it in IIS, everything works fine.

How can I stop this from happening in VS?

Do I have to bring those config settings back into the web.config?

Casini doesn't have a problem with this config, nor the IIS dev server, and the file is NOT in the GAC (not the 3.5 version anyways, the 4.0 is), and I won't put it there for this one problem (I'll move everything back into the web.config proper) and the dll file *is* in the bin folder.

Comment: Adding an accept mark because I'm sure that you gave me insight, but mostly because I moved on. If anyone has a better answer they can add it and I'll reconsider a checkmark. The question is at best an annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Web.DataVisualization` assembly into your Visual Studio project. Visual Studio doesn't compile against any assemblies not listed in the "References" folder.

In the Solution Explorer, under your project, right-click on the "References" folder and click "Add Reference..."

[image]

Select and add the missing assembly.

[image]

Problem solved.

Comment: But it's not installed to the GAC, and when I install it via this method, it still bitches it can't find it. The ONLY solution is to install it to the GAC, which I was purposefully avoiding. I wanted my dev machine to as closely mimic the server as possible, and while I _can_ (and have, for now) install it to the GAC, that shouldn't be a requirement, because it's in the /bin folder, as I'm told it should be. So, Problem **not** solved, but good writeup on what needs to be done to add it.

Comment: @jcolebrand First, what's the chances that your solution properties is incorrectly targeting one of the .NET client profiles instead of the full .NET profile? See: http://www.atulverma.com/2010/07/setting-right-target-framework-for-net.html -- When you say the assembly is not in the GAC, are you saying it completely doesn't exist on the dev machine??? That's not right. Check the target.

Comment: I do mean that it's not on the dev machine, except in the solution /bin folder. This is a "website" and not a solution. But I know full well how to tell that the solution references are pointing to the bin folder vs the GAC. Using the Website menu, Start Options, References, hence I knew that it was looking to find it in the GAC and not in the /bin folder. For some reason, it believes the dll MUST be in the GAC, when there's no file/reference pointing it to look there.

Comment: @jcolebrand I'm a bit confused at this point. When you install the .NET Framework all of the assemblies should be available and you shouldn't have to install anything anywhere. But you do have to add a Reference to the assembly in your project. Something is screwy.

Comment: @jcolebrand Here's a thought--when you installed the .NET Framework on this machine, did you install the Client Profile version or the FULL version? The former would not include this assembly. Reinstall the Full .NET 3.5 Framework (or 4.0) and related service packs: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've installed the full package of .NET 4.0 and .NET 3.5, and in regards to .NET 4.0 the charting component is indeed installed in the GAC. The issue is specifically for .NET 3.5 where the dll is in the /bin folder.

Comment: @jcolebrand It makes no sense that a standard .NET Framework assembly would need to be placed in the bin folder. It should be available from the system.

Comment: But you're misunderstanding something here. .NET 3.5 did not include the DataVisualization tools because they didn't exist yet. They were purchased by Microsoft from someone else and "integrated into" the .NET toolkit, and it wasn't "official" until 4.0. So the .NET 3.5 integration stuff requires an additional install.

Comment: @jcolebrand Okay, I see. Well the assembly is on my dev machine, so I presume it comes with .NET 4.0, but I take it you need to target 3.5? Here, try this one: http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/04/systemwebdatavisualization-missing.html

Comment: And finally you've joined the conversation where I am. I'm trying to AVOID installing the .NET 3.5 charting component to the GAC on the dev machine.

Comment: @jcolebrand Running out of ideas here. I found this page with several suggestions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/d976b659-264a-4731-935c-08c02865002f

Comment: Running out of ideas is why I posted expounding on the particular problem I'm having. This is probably better cross-posted to Connect (If I recall the name of the Microsoft bug tracker) but since we're going to rewrite this app as .NET 4/MVC3+Razor in the next 12 months, and this is purely a Cassini issue, I'm not going to stress over it anymore. It was an annoyance so I tossed out a question.

Comment: @jcolebrand Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance. Best of luck!

Comment: You gave it the old college try, and that's appreciated.

Comment: Adding an accept mark because I'm sure that you gave me insight, but mostly because I moved on. If anyone has a better answer they can add it and I'll reconsider a checkmark. The question is at best an annoyance.